# How to change the Sitecore commerce authoring url for sitecore 9.3?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

When I had installed the commerce in my development environment then the commerce authoring URL is set as https://commerceauthoring.sc930.local so my request goes to this URL when I click on the business tools. Now I want to move requests to go on https://localhost:5000 so what are the configs I need to follow?

The reason I want to have the business tools' request go on localhost:5000 because I am trying to connect the Commerce VS solution to the business tools as per [this blog](https://sandeeppote.com/2020/04/15/step-by-step-setup-development-environment-for-sitecore-commerce-9-3-engine/). And this can debug the plugin only for https://localhost:5000

Answer (score 0):

Open `\businesstoolsfolder\assets\config.json`.

Verify the EngineUri (case sensitive)
If that is correct, verify the `config.json` of your Visual Studio CE project.

Check the AllowedOrigins section and see if it has the right business tools url.

Restart IIS.

Refresh your browser cache before opening business tools.

If it still doesn't work then try:

Open the identity server folder in inetpub and goto the file:    `SitecoreIdentityServer\Config\Production\Sitecore.Commerce.IdentityServer.Host.xml`

Verify AllowedCORSOrigins setting.

Check entry under AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2. It should have an entry for localhost:5000 combination. it is also case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks @sc.kautilya. Yes, it was a caching issue but I have updated the entry for the https://localhost:5000 in the AllowedCors but still, bizFx is blocking the localhost:5000 call.

Comment: check http vs https configuration. What is in the logs?

Comment: I did 1. Entered the https://localhost:5000 in the identity server's Host.xml file and 2. Entered the same URL in the assets/config.json.

Comment: Did you restart identity server as well?

Comment: Yes, even after that I checked in the private window. In the console of chrome, it is showing that bizfx.sc930.local has blocked the for https://localhost:5000 due to CORS policy.

Comment: your commerce engine config.json has bizfx.sc930.local  or localhost:4200 as business tools endpoint? AppSettings\AllowedOrigins

Comment: The issue looks like is that ur Commerce Engine does not think that the request coming from bizfx.sc930.local  is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the `commerceauthoring.sc930.local`  in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yoursite\App_Config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config`.

In this file you need to replace your `commerceauthoring.sc930.local` with `localhost:5000` in `ShopServiceurl`, `CommerceOpsServiceurl`.
[image]

Hope this might help someone in the future.